# How to Avoid Red-Eye in Photos?

Tags: flash, shooting-technique, red-eye

Although tools exist to remove red-eye in post-production, what's the best way to avoid it while creating the photograph in the field?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To understand how to prevent red-eye you need to understand what causes it.

Red eye is caused by light from a flash that is close to the lens entering the subjects pupils and bouncing off the rear of the eye back into the lens. (The main cause for the red colour is the blood in the back of the retina). [Wikipedia has more info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-eye_effect).

To prevent red-eye you need to prevent this light bounce back. There are several ways to achieve this.

1. Pre-flash. By flashing a bright light prior to taking the main photo. This causes the subjects pupils to narrow and reduces the amount of red eye. Many modern compacts have red eye reduction modes that do this by flashing multiple times before the main flash, or providing a continuous bright light in place of a quick flash.
2. Use an angled flash to direct the light to bounce of a wall or ceiling to prevent the direct bounce back.
3. Use a flash that is separate from the camera so the light bouncing back does not bounce directly back down the axis of the lens.

[image: prevention of redeye]

If you have a compact camera it is likely your only option is number 1. With an SLR you have more choices.

Comment: 4. No flash :) :)

Comment: @Rog No need to avoid flash all together, just learn how to use it properly, bouncing is the number one way to achieve flattering well lit photos in low light, and it also prevents red eye!

Comment: @Matt, apologies if my tongue in cheek comment came across in the wrong light (no pun intended). I was merely trying to point out an option people often forget to consider, especially with the emergence of cameras and lenses that perform very well in low (natural) light. It was in no way meant to reduce the validity of the other 3 options with which I am quite familiar and capable.

Answer (score 11):

Using an off camera flash, or bouncing the flash off the ceiling/wall, will help to avoid red-eye.

For a more in-depth answer this is a good article about [red-eye control](http://www.dpfwiw.com/red-eye.htm).

Answer (score 6):

If your subjects are prone to red eye, prefiring a flash pulse before taking the shot will make their iris contract, reducing redeye. Many camera's have this as a setting for the flash.

Comment: Preflash works for some people, but for others, it triggers a blink reflex.

The most reliable solution is to move the flash off camera.

Answer (score 1):

If you're stuck with a point and shoot camera you can try to soften the flash in various ways: a piece of scotch tape over the flash, a tissue held over it, a piece of paper... all of these will allow a varying amounts of flash to pass through but with diffuse light which will prevent red-eye. You'll need to experiment to know exactly which works best for the subject you're shooting.